# Why the $L^2$- norm of a signal is corresponded to its energy?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am  a  newcomer in signal processing. I saw that the $L^2$-norm of a signal is also applied as its energy! How is this concept illustrated for those ones who are working in pure math.

Comment: In pure mathematics it's just a definition.

Comment: Well it's just a name, but intuiviely it measures how much the signal deviates from the zero function.